# Replacing NaTs in a DataFrame using shift

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a dataframe from an Excel spreadsheet where the data column is incomplete:

```
    Date           Value
0   2020-04-29       144
1   NaT              158
2   NaT              134
3   2020-04-30       114
4   NaT              153
```

and I'd like to fill in the NaTs by replacing them with the date from the line above. The slow method works:

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if pd.isnull(df.iat[i,0]):
        df.iat[i, 0] = df.iat[i-1, 0]
```

but the methods I think ought to work, don't. Both of these replace the first NaT they can encounter but skip NaTs after that (are they working on copies of the data?)

```
df["Date"] = np.where(df["Date"].isnull(), df["Date"].shift(1), df["Date"])
df['Date'].mask(df['Date'].isnull(), df['Date'].shift(1), inplace=True)
```

Is there any quick way of doing this?

A

Comment: `df["Date"].ffill()`  ? can you post te expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
df.ffill()
```

- If "Date" values are string, you can convert "NaT" into actual `NaN` value using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.replace("NaT", np.NaN).ffill()
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace `"NaT"` string to actuel `NaN` values.
- Fill all `NaN` cells from the previous not `NaN` cell using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html).

---

**Code + illustration**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(df.replace("NaT", np.NaN))
#          Date  Value
# 0  2020-04-29    144
# 1         NaN    158
# 2         NaN    134
# 3  2020-04-30    114
# 4         NaN    153
print(df.replace("NaT", np.NaN).ffill())
#          Date  Value
# 0  2020-04-29    144
# 1  2020-04-29    158
# 2  2020-04-29    134
# 3  2020-04-30    114
# 4  2020-04-30    153
```